# Need assistance with Jquery UI Drag and Drop instance offset issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, offset

I am working on a drag and drop feature and run into an issue with offset on dragable instance. for some reason when I use the following code below my **drop area** changes positions. Without the offset, my dragable items are not following the mouse and floating at the top of the div while being draged. The page example http://54.162.89.47. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
start: function(event, ui){  
$(this).draggable('instance').offset.click = {
    left: Math.floor(ui.helper.width() / 2),
    top: Math.floor(ui.helper.height() / 2)
};
}
```

The whole script looks as following:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({ 
cursor: "crosshair", 
revert: "invalid", 
helper: "clone",
tolerance: "fit",
start: function(event, ui){
    console.log($(this).draggable('instance').offset.click)
    $(this).draggable('instance').offset.click = {
        left: Math.floor(ui.helper.width() / 2),
        top: Math.floor(ui.helper.height() / 2)
    }; 
}
});
var text = '', droppedOn = '';

$("#drop").droppable({ accept: ".draggable", 
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("drop");
        $(this).removeClass("border").removeClass("over");
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        droppedOn = $(this);
        text = $(dropped).attr('data-text');
        $('#drop-text').html('<p>'+text+'</p>');    
        $(dropped).clone().appendTo(droppedOn);         
    }, 
    over: function(event, elem) {
        $(this).addClass("over");
        $(droppedOn).find('img').remove();
    },
    out: function(event, elem) {
        $(this).removeClass("over");
    }
});
```

Comment: Since this is using WordPress, there are a LOT of styling elements that could be influencing this. It may be best to create a stand alone example with just the specific elements in use. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Started one and could not capture all the CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/y9dw1L4m/5/

Comment: This had to do with styles you are correct. Apparently, the ui draggable element can only have left top or left bottom styles. Took a while to figure it out. Thank you.